# Cannot get managed identity token in Azure Data Factory when connecting to Oracle DB using Azure Key Vault

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I am trying to connect to an on-prem Oracle database using key vault secret. I have set-up an Integration Runtime and are able to connect to the database if I manually fill in the connection string details. However, if I use a key vault secret for the PW I get this error:

The ADF have been granted all secret permissions to the key vault. Seems like a permission issue in Azure. Any ideas?

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmpMJ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5pMx.png)

Comment: Have you added the Managed Identity Object ID of your ADF to your key valut?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your Managed Identity Object ID to your Azure Key valut, then the ADF can access the secret.

1. In ADF's homepage, you can view the `Managed Identity Object ID` at **Properties** tab.

[image]

2. In Azure key valut, you can click `Add access policy` and search the ADF's Managed Identity Object ID, then configure the secret permissions to the ADF.

[image]

After that, you can test connection again.